# Can you determine if a user can be direct messaged using discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to know if my bot is allowed to message a user without messaging them first. I wrote some working code but it requires the user to be messaged first.

```
user=bot.get_user(member.id)
try:
    await user.send("")
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
    canmessage=False
except:
    canmessage=True
```

The code sends the user a blank message and if the user cannot be messaged it returns False, and if the message fails to send (because it is blank), it returns True.
When used in certain contexts this can mark the bot for spam, even though no messages were received.
If there is a proper way to do this through the Discord API I am unaware of it.
I have searched the internet but I found no info on this nor have I found anyone else asking a similar question.
I want to know if this is possible in the Discord API, preferably using discord.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **create_dm** method on the User/Member Object

```
user=bot.get_user(member.id)
try:
   await user.create_dm()
   can_message_user = True
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
   can_message_user = False
#do other stuff
```

Comment: `user.create_dm` is called [internally](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/45d498c1b76deaf3b394d17ccf56112fa691d160/discord/user.py#L454) in `user.send`, so it's essentially the same.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the user has been messaged previously, as it will still return true. If the ability to message a user has changed this will still return True.